# One Hot Encoding Sklearn, Multiple Columns Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

**Hello!**

I am trying to encode a set of features in the housing price prediction data set. I am using the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoded = pd.DataFrame(OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(categorical_df[['MSZoning']]), index=categorical_df.index)
encoded.head()
```

The result I am getting is as follows:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| **0** | (0, 3)\t1.0 |
| **1** | (0, 3)\t1.0 |
| **2** | (0, 3)\t1.0 |

How can I get a proper data frame in this situation?

**EDIT**
The data for this project is available at
[Housing Price Data](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/home-data-for-ml-course/data)

Comment: better show minimal working code with example data which gives this result.

Comment: The above code is working and converting the feature to OH encoded data frame. But the dataframe is not formatted properly.

Comment: I have no idea what you have in original data - and your data can be the problem.

Comment: How about trying with `OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(categorical_df[['MSZoning']]).iloc[:, 0]`